# SSH Between Two Servers with Existing SSH Keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am trying to use transfer files between two cloud-based server instances, both running Ubuntu 16.04. Both are configured with SSH key authentication, and I am able to successfully SSH into each using PuTTY.

How do I configure it so I can PuTTY SSH into one and then SCP transfer files to the other?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate a private/public keypair for the server that needs to send the files. Then you need to copy the public key to the other server for the correct user.

```bsh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
# follow the prompts that this command gives you
# you don't have to set a password on the key if you want 
# to use ssh in scripts, now copy the pub key to the server
ssh-copy-id user@otherserver
```

You will need to temporarily allow password authentication in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the server receiving the the public keys.  After the `ssh-copy-id` command has completed you can set it back to keys only.

Digital Ocean has a great guide on [How to set up SSH keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).

Comment: Am I not able to use the keys I already have? I can SSH into both with PuTTY, I just can't get one to SSH to the other, so I'm assuming it's a config issue or not putting the private key in the right place.

Comment: You can put your private key from your workstation on the servers, but I generally think it is safer to make new keys.  If they all have the same private key, then they could ssh into unrelated project's you have using different servers

Comment: You can also configure remote host authentication if you don't want to make more keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run ssh authentication agent on your client (it is called ssh-agent in openssh and AFAIR - pageant in putty) and allow authentication agent forwarding in your connections (ForwardAgent yes in openssh, no idea in putty).